# how to implement an integrated rechargable battery in my project?

Tags: power-supply

i'm constructing a simple portable speaker/amplifier and want it to contain am integrated rechargeable power source.

What's the best/safest way to integrate a rechargeable battery?

i want it to work much like an electric shaver or mobile phone would, with a transformer integrated into the plug, and with a coaxial power connector used to transfer electricity to the unit.

thanks.

battery type: probably ni-mh i think? i need something with plenty of ampere-hours, but am concerned about making it safe enough to leave charging overnight. also i need a simple and cheap solution!

Comment: Battery Type? As different batteries need different charging methods. Such as Ni-Cad and NiMH can be charged with a constant current source.

Comment: thanks for the response - have amended the question and am now researching constant current source!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a battery management IC.  Searching Digikey for "Battery management" and then filtering by battery chemistry and then price, gave me the TSM101/A.  For less than a dollar, it seems to be capable of what you want.

Just replace the mains and rectifier portion of the circuit with a wall wart.  There are some examples with charge status LEDs.

Here is the [data sheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001116.pdf).